# Toggling mutex lock using guard

Tags: c++, mutex

How can I refactor the following code to use the recommended lock_guards?

```
bool locked = false;
bool sync() {
    if (locked) {
        mutex.unlock();
    } else {
        mutex.lock();
    }
    locked = !locked;
    return locked;
}
```

Desired usage pattern:

```
while (sync()) {
    // do safe things
}
```

Basically I am trying to emulate the `with` statement from Python. Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Lock
with Lock():
    # do safe things
```

Comment: Could you instead provide a Python example with the `with` and a mutex that you would like to have in C++?

Comment: What do you want the meaning of `sync()` to be? just toggle a lock?

Comment: Bad design calls for bad code. There should no need **at all** for lock toggling.

Comment: @michalsrb I added an example
@RichardHodges Yes I want the lock to be held for exactly one iteration of the `while` loop and then released.

Comment: @SergeyA How else to synchronize multiple actors writing to a file for example?

Comment: Every actor should obtain a lock, write to a file, release the lock. Unconditionally.

Comment: @SergeyA the convoluted logic inside `sync()` supposedly achieves that when plugged into a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a scope:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};

    // Your operations here
}
```

If you really want to have a scope with a header, C++17's `if`-with-initializer can be bent into that shape easily:

```
if(std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex}; true) {
    // Your operations here
}
```

... and then you can hide it inside a (thoughtfully named) macro.

Finally, and with my declining of all responsibility about how you use that thing, here is a C++14 implementation:

```
template <class T>
struct Lock {
    Lock(T &mtx)
    : guard{mtx} { }

    constexpr operator bool() const { return false; }

    std::lock_guard<T> guard;
};

// Replace the pragmas for a compiler other than Clang or GCC
// so it doesn't complain about the unused variable
#define withLock(mtx) \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wunused-variable\"") \
    if(auto const &_lockGuard = Lock<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(mtx)>>{mtx}); else \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")

// ...

withLock(mutex) {
    // Your operations here
}
```

... but really, a simple scope works fine and doesn't have to be documented and argued for against code reviewers.

Comment: c++17 or not, that second idea needs to go in the bin. It has 'confusing code' written all over it.

Comment: @RichardHodges wel you definitely won't like that edit then :)

Comment: @AnonymousEntity if you use the `#define` method your co-workers will ask for you to be fired.

Answer (score 5):

Just create a [locker](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);` and mutex will be automatically released at the end of `lock`'s life.

```
std::mutex mutex;
....
{
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
     // do do safe things
     // mutex will be released here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design is not supported by lock guards, and there is a good reason for it. You shouldn't ever have the need to *toggle* the lock. The correct usage pattern for shared resource is that every thread accessing the resource first acquires the lock through the guard, than uses the resource, and than exists - which triggers automatic lock release.

No one ever needs to toggle the lock.

Comment: In my opinion you are still toggling the lock in that case, but letting the c++ rules about scope handle the toggling instead of doing it explicitly. Explicitly or implicitly, the mutex is still being toggled.

Answer (score 0):

A full example of how i'd normally approach it:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

// here is the relevant function

template<class Mutex, class F>
decltype(auto) with_lock(Mutex& mutex, F&& func)
{
    using mutex_type = std::decay_t<Mutex>;
    using lock_type = std::lock_guard<mutex_type>;
    lock_type lock { mutex };
    return func();
}

// here is a test

int main()
{
    std::mutex m;
    std::default_random_engine eng { std::random_device()() };

    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
    {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [i, &m, &eng]
        {
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(10, 100);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(dist(eng)));
            with_lock(m, [i]
            {
                std::cout << "thread index: " << i << std::endl;
            });
        }));
    }

    for (auto& f : futures)
    {
        f.get();
    }
}
```

sample output (note, no races on cout):

```
thread index: 63
thread index: 62
thread index: 30
thread index: 49
thread index: 25
thread index: 1
thread index: 58
thread index: 33
thread index: 72
thread index: 75
thread index: 11
thread index: 22
thread index: 46
thread index: 41
thread index: 20
thread index: 36
thread index: 37
thread index: 23
thread index: 45
thread index: 82
thread index: 0
thread index: 28
thread index: 88
thread index: 3
thread index: 74
thread index: 84
thread index: 31
thread index: 9
thread index: 34
thread index: 93
thread index: 24
thread index: 98
thread index: 38
thread index: 55
thread index: 43
thread index: 52
thread index: 40
thread index: 69
thread index: 67
thread index: 91
thread index: 89
thread index: 86
thread index: 76
thread index: 21
thread index: 29
thread index: 53
thread index: 81
thread index: 10
thread index: 96
thread index: 68
thread index: 7
thread index: 73
thread index: 78
thread index: 54
thread index: 59
thread index: 83
thread index: 60
thread index: 47
thread index: 19
thread index: 6
thread index: 17
thread index: 56
thread index: 57
thread index: 66
thread index: 70
thread index: 39
thread index: 26
thread index: 13
thread index: 79
thread index: 15
thread index: 5
thread index: 94
thread index: 14
thread index: 77
thread index: 32
thread index: 48
thread index: 87
thread index: 92
thread index: 61
thread index: 80
thread index: 18
thread index: 27
thread index: 12
thread index: 71
thread index: 4
thread index: 2
thread index: 99
thread index: 35
thread index: 50
thread index: 51
thread index: 65
thread index: 64
thread index: 16
thread index: 42
thread index: 90
thread index: 8
thread index: 44
thread index: 85
thread index: 97
thread index: 95
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a pretty evil, but working, hack:

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

#define with(m) for (std::unique_ptr<std::lock_guard<std::mutex>> lock( \
                     new std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m)); lock; lock.reset())

int main()
{
  std::mutex m;
  with (m)
  {
    std::cout << "got the mutex" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The `with(m)` expands to a `for` loop header which

- creates a `unique_ptr` to the `lock_guard` that holds the mutex
- in the loop condition, verifies that the pointer is non-null
- in the increment part, resets the pointer.

That has the effect of executing the loop body which follows the `with()` macro exactly once, with the lock being held.  Slightly hackish because of the macro and the pointer, but nevertheless a bit cleaner than constructing a `while` loop and toggling the mutex state.

If you have C++14, you can simplify the macro a bit using [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).  If you can use C++17, [Quentin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40998737/3233921) will be more elegant.

Of course, this isn't really the C++ way of doing it, just a hack to get some syntactic sugar.  So, unless you really insist on following a Python-like syntax, you could just use the standard C++ way of using a `lock_guard` like so:

```
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
  // Do whatever
}
```

Comment: Why not make it a non-evil non-hack?

Comment: Well, how would you like it? It emulates a `with` statement with Python-like behaviour. But it's not really the C++ way of doing it. Hence evil and hack.

Comment: @RichardHodges That better?

Comment: if it contains a #define, it's an unmaintainable pollution of the global namespace what will cause programs that once compiled, to suddenly no longer compile. Use an inline function or template function for goodness' sake.

Comment: Of course there are cleaner ways of doing it, after all there is a reason why I said “evil” and “hack”. But it's the only way to reproduce the Python style exactly. Whether or not that is acceptable for the OP is their decision, based on the alternatives we offer. No reason to be upset though. :)